# .htaccess HTTP or HTTPS depending on subdomain level

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, ssl-certificate

I can't afford a wildcard SSL certificate for an infinite level of subdomains, I only have a `*.domain.tld` wildcard. So I want HTTPS requests to be re-written to HTTP requests **if** there is more than one level of subdomains in the `%{HTTP_HOST}` variable. And HTTP requests should be rewritten to HTTPS requests if there is none or 1 subdomain.

For example:

```
www.domain.tld       -> 1 subdomain(s) HTTPS
domain.tld           -> 0 subdomain(s) HTTPS
sub.domain.tld       -> 1 subdomain(s) HTTPS
two.sub.domains.tld  -> 2 subdomain(s) HTTP
a.b.c.domain.tld     -> 3 subdomain(s) HTTP
```

This is the only solution I can think of that doesn't involve me buying a wildcard certificate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
RewriteEngine on

# redirect http to https with 0 or 1 subdomain
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^.]+\.){1,2}[^.]+$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,L,R=301] 

# redirect https to http with 2 or more subdomains
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^.]+\.){3,}[^.]+$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,L,R=301]
```

You can not avoid the SSL security error message with https to http redirect

Comment: Aah too bad the error still shows up, otherwise it works. Thanks!

Comment: This is related to SSL. It should never be possible to remove this message. Because we try from a secure domain that is not really the good domain.